# I need assistance in Python - Searching within a function

Tags: python

```
def find(word, letter):
    index = 0
    while index < len(word):
        if word[index] == letter:
            return index
        index = index + 1
    return -1
```

I get this...

The exercise says:

> Modify find so that it has a third parameter, the index in word where
>   it should start looking.

Pardon my newbiness at this but... when it says modify 'find' so it has a third parameter...`find(word,letter,thirdparameter)` or put a third para within the function definition? Also the index in word where it should start looking, I'm not too sure if I'm misinterpreting but it wants to take the index in a word and start looking at a random index number? H

Comment: is that code? shouldnt that be properly indented?

Comment: Not a *random* index, an *arbitrary* index. One that defaults to the current 0.

Comment: +1 to counteract -1.  The question includes the homework tag and seems within bounds of the Stack Overflow FAQ.

Comment: My apologies. I'm not really after the answer to the question but more of the process in getting there since ultimately, the exercise question didn't 'click' in my head what I need to do. This is homework, though I'm more for learning and acknowledging than just getting the answers and submitting for grade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is asking you to create a third parameter for the starting index.  The new signature would be something like `find(letter, word, startindex)`.  It would work like this:

```
>>> find('red blue', 'd', 0) # starts at index 0 and finds 'd' at index 2
2
>>> find('red blue', 'd', 3) # starts at index 3 and finds no d's
-1
>>> find('red blue', 'e', 3) # starts at index 3, so misses the 'e' at index 1
7
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This makes perfect sense. I appreciate the help.

Comment: You're welcome.  You can accept this answer (or anyone else's) by clicking the check mark to the left of the question.  That gains me 15 reputation points and you gain 2.  If you end up asking more questions on Stack Overflow some may stop answering if you have a history of not accepting answers.

Comment: To make it default to index zero you would define function as `def find(letter, word, startindex=0'`

Answer (score 2):

> when it says modify 'find' so it has a third parameter...find(word,letter,thirdparameter)

Right.

> or put a third para within the function definition?

Um.  That's the same thing.  Add a third parameter in the function definition.

Comment: so I could either place a third parameter in the function or not, and write a line defining a third within the definition?

Comment: @G.G: "place a third parameter in the function or not, and write a line defining a third within the definition" are the exact same thing.  It's hard to see what you're asking unless you provide concrete examples of what you think the difference is.  The words have the same meaning.  But you keep writing them like they're somehow different.  Please **update** your question with both examples of these changes about which you keep saying "or".

Comment: <code>def find(word, letter, startat): 
                 definition block of find()

same as

        find(word, letter):
            startat = index
            index = input('choose number ') 


are these the same thing?

Comment: sorry, I'm still trying to figure out how to format this to display correctly.

Comment: @G.G: You can't format code in a comment.  `index = input('choose number ')` is not a parameter to the function.  It's just code.

Comment: @G.G: Don't apologize.  Please **update** your question with both examples of these changes about which you keep saying "or".

Answer (score 2):

This means that you should modify the function so that it takes an additional parameter, which will be the index to start at in the string before looking for the match.

Here is some sample output after making this change that may help you understand:

```
>>> find('abc abc', 'b', 0)  # starting at beginning, will find the first 'b'
1
>>> find('abc abc', 'b', 2)  # starting after first 'b', will find the second 'b'
5
>>> find('abc abc', 'b', 6)  # starting after both 'b's, won't find a match
-1
```

Comment: Excellent. The 3rd parameter is the designated place to start but not including the one it's currently on.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it takes two parameters, `word` and `letter`. There's already a variable in the code that is used for the index, so pull it out of there and promote it to a parameter with a default value.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find(word, letter, startat):
    try:
        return word[startat:].index(letter)+startat
    except:
        return -1
```

To keep the original implementation:

```
def find(word, letter, startat):
    for index in range(startat, len(word)+1):
        if word[index] == letter:
            return index
    return -1
```

Comment: If you were to submit this as the answer to the homework question above, then it would be wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the bad writing of the code. I'm new to this and the language. It's actually study guide examples. 

Pardon my lack of intel on this but can you dumb this down and explain what the exercise is asking and what should be done to the code to make it so? I take it as adding more code and not changing the original.(or not)

Comment: Your function find() has two arguments: word and letter. You are asked to modify the function as "def find(word, letter, thirdparameter)", where you should use a proper name as "def find(word, letter, startat)". Then you have to modify the code inside this function such that searching starts at "startat", not at "index=0", but at "index=startat".

Comment: -1: Don't answer someone's homework for them.  You're not getting credit for the coursework, are you?

Comment: THANK GUYS! ALL OF YOU... I appreciate the knowledge and time you guys have taken to help a newb. In short... I FINALLY GET IT! Thank you again!

Comment: @G.G: I hope you try to understand all proposed solutions !

Comment: The way it works. I submit a bunch of examples in my lesson and If I have trouble with one, my professor gives me the code to work with and explain in detail what I'm missing. It's no different here however; I don't have to wait 24hrs for him to respond. It's not about the credit but the acknowledgement and understanding of what I'm reading and practicing just that.

Comment: I will rocksportrocker...it will take me a little bit of time to instill the different solutions in my head.

Comment: Plus, this is an online course and it's proven to be a challenge since it's all about researching and learning on your own. I rarely have blocks like this unless I truly am misinterpreting the question.

Comment: Go on asking ! Learning programming with python is valuable and big fun ! Thank you teacher that he has not chosen Java ;-)

Comment: Your right rsr, I have tons of fun writing code. It can also be really frustrating at times but I enjoy the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

The program will set to exit when it finds the first occurrence of the 'letter'.

```
def find(word, letter, index):
    while index < len(word):
        if word[index] == letter:
            return index
        index += 1
    return -1
```

If we start to search at the index 1, 'b' is found here, 1 is returned and the program exits.

```
>>>print(find('abc abc', 'b', 1))
1
```

If we start to search at index 2, 'b' isn't found here, the program will increment by 1 until 'b' is found. It returns 5, which is the index of the second letter 'b'.

```
>>>print(find('abc abc', 'b', 2))
5
```

If we start to search at index 6, the program returns -1 since there is no longer any letter 'b'.

```
>>>print(find('abc abc', 'b', 6))
-1
```